# Eliminate duplicates in the List and sum up the quantity field

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have a List consisting of ID and quantity. IDs are repeated with different quantities. I want to remove the duplicate IDs and add the quanties.
Eg: ID1 :4
    ID2 :5
    ID1 :3
I want this as ID1:7
               ID2:5
I tried with LINQ. I am able to delete the duplicate but not add the quantity.

```
    List<PrintDetails> myList = printDetailsList
                                             .GroupBy(s => s.MasterID)
                                             .Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault())
                                             .OrderBy(s => s.Quantity)
                                             .ToList();
```

Comment: So you want to get aggregated quantities by id (as opposed to removing duplicate ids)?

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to return a new object with the sums:

```
List<PrintDetails> myList = printDetailsList
    .GroupBy(s => s.MasterID)
    .Select(grp => new PrintDetails() { MasterID = grp.Key, Quantity = grp.Sum(s => s.Quantity) }) // create a new object with the Id and quantity by sum
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Quantity) // based on the example in the question you actually want to order from highest quantity to lowest
    .ToList();
```

When you group a list, you get a grouping that contains a `Key` and is an enumerable of the items. So you can use the key as the masterId (since that's what it is) and then use the enumerable to sum quantities.

I also fixed your OrderBy since it seemed to be the wrong way around for your example.

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/QKLBJ33803)